# Swift iPad - buttons not working

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uibutton

I have iPad screen:

1) Buttons are not clickable when changing their positions.
2) Circular button image is getting stretched.

I need to create button set given in the below screen.

[image: My screen]

I am using following code to create the button set.

```
class MyCommonViewController: UIViewController {

    var button: UIButton?
    var Circularbutton: UIButton?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var xMargin:CGFloat = 20.0
        var yTopMargin:CGFloat = 40.0
        var CircularBtnxMargin:CGFloat = 180.0
        var CircularBtnyTopMargin:CGFloat = 200.0

        var i = 1     

        let TextArray = ["Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3", "Button 4", "Button 5", "Button 6"]

        for index in 1...6
        {
            button = UIButton()
            button?.tag=index
            var buttonFrame = self.view.frame
            buttonFrame.origin.x += xMargin
            buttonFrame.origin.y += yTopMargin
            buttonFrame.size.width = 200
            buttonFrame.size.height = 200

            button?.frame = buttonFrame
            button?.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0            
            button?.layer.zPosition = 10

            button?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()              

            button?.setTitle(TextArray[index-1], forState: UIControlState.Normal)            
            button?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyCommonViewController.BigButtonTouched), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

            self.view.addSubview(button!)


            Circularbutton = UIButton()
            var CbuttonFrame = self.view.frame           

            CbuttonFrame.origin = CGPoint(x:CircularBtnxMargin, y:CircularBtnyTopMargin)
            CbuttonFrame.size.width = 50
            CbuttonFrame.size.height = 50          

            Circularbutton?.frame = CbuttonFrame


            Circularbutton?.tag=index
            Circularbutton?.layer.zPosition = 100


            let image = UIImage(named: "que2.png") as UIImage?
            Circularbutton?.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Circularbutton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyCommonViewController.questionButtonPressed), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


            self.view.addSubview(Circularbutton!)

            xMargin+=250.0
            CircularBtnxMargin+=250.0
            i+=1

            if(i > 3 )
            {
                yTopMargin+=300.0
                xMargin=20.0
                CircularBtnyTopMargin+=300.0
                CircularBtnxMargin=180.0
                i=1
            }
        }

    }

}
```

1) But the buttons with question mark are not clickable except for the initial two buttons.

2) My second problem is that the circular button image is displaying rough uneven border.

Can you help me out?

Edit:

```
func questionButtonPressed(sender:UIButton!) {

let btn:UIButton = sender

print("Circular Button Pressed - \(btn.tag)")
}


func BigButtonTouched(sender:UIButton!) {

let bigBtn:UIButton = sender

print("Button Pressed - \(bigBtn.tag)")

}
```

Comment: for index in 1...6. I think you need to loop from 0 to 5 as it is index of array.

Comment: Can you share content of: questionButtonPressed func?

Comment: @RoyK - added function code in the questions for questionButtonPressed and BigButtonTouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the buttons on each iteration of the for loop, not outside of the for loop. See code (you will need to remove all forced unwraps):

```
class MyCommonViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var xMargin:CGFloat = 20.0
        var yTopMargin:CGFloat = 40.0
        var CircularBtnxMargin:CGFloat = 180.0
        var CircularBtnyTopMargin:CGFloat = 200.0

        var i = 1     

        let TextArray = ["Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3", "Button 4", "Button 5", "Button 6"]

        for index in 1...6
        {
            let button = UIButton()
            button?.tag=index
            var buttonFrame = self.view.frame
            buttonFrame.origin.x += xMargin
            buttonFrame.origin.y += yTopMargin
            buttonFrame.size.width = 200
            buttonFrame.size.height = 200

            button?.frame = buttonFrame
            button?.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0            
            button?.layer.zPosition = 10

            button?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()              

            button?.setTitle(TextArray[index-1], forState: UIControlState.Normal)            
            button?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyCommonViewController.BigButtonTouched), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

            self.view.addSubview(button!)


            let Circularbutton = UIButton()
            var CbuttonFrame = self.view.frame           

            CbuttonFrame.origin = CGPoint(x:CircularBtnxMargin, y:CircularBtnyTopMargin)
            CbuttonFrame.size.width = 50
            CbuttonFrame.size.height = 50          

            Circularbutton?.frame = CbuttonFrame


            Circularbutton?.tag=index
            Circularbutton?.layer.zPosition = 100


            let image = UIImage(named: "que2.png") as UIImage?
            Circularbutton?.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            Circularbutton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyCommonViewController.questionButtonPressed), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


            self.view.addSubview(Circularbutton!)

            xMargin+=250.0
            CircularBtnxMargin+=250.0
            i+=1

            if(i > 3 )
            {
                yTopMargin+=300.0
                xMargin=20.0
                CircularBtnyTopMargin+=300.0
                CircularBtnxMargin=180.0
                i=1
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried declaring buttons on each iteration of the for loop but still it has no effect.The circular buttons except the starting two are not clickable